# in c, value is changing from the end of a function to outside the function after function call

Tags: c

In line 77 v->size is 0 while in line 186 v-size is 2. I dont understand why this is so because line 186 is at the very end of the function definition of void _setCapacityDynArr(struct DynArr *v, int newCap)(in line 140) and line 77 is right after the call to the function. Somehow between the end of the function and the next line after the function call the value has changed. I thought because v is a pointer it should retain the value. If someone could please tell me why the value is changing it would be greatly appreciated. I've run out of ideas and have no idea what to do.

http://pastebin.com/tWR6w8rG

```
   /* 
 * File:   main.c
 * Author: user1
 *
 * Created on April 7, 2015, 3:57 PM
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
/* 
 * File:   main.c
 * Author: user1
 *
 * Created on April 7, 2015, 3:57 PM
 */

/*
 * 
 */
# ifndef TYPE
# define TYPE int
# endif

struct DynArr
{
    TYPE *data;
        int size;
int capacity;
};

/* pointer to the data array */
/* Number of elements in the array */
/* capacity ofthe array */
void initDynArr(struct DynArr *v, int capacity)
{
    v->data = malloc(sizeof(TYPE) * capacity);
    //assert(v->data != 0);
    v->size = 0;
    v->capacity = capacity;
}

void freeDynArr(struct DynArr *v)
{
    if(v->data != 0)
    {
        free(v->data); /* free the space on the heap */
        v->data = 0;
        /* make it point to null */
    }
    v->size = 0;
    v->capacity = 0;
}

int sizeDynArr( struct DynArr *v)
{
    return v->size;
}

/*
void addDynArr(struct DynArr *v, TYPE val)
{
// Check to see if a resize is necessary 
if(v->size == v->capacity)
_setCapacityDynArr(v, 2 * v->capacity);
v->data[v->size] = val;
v->size++;
}

*/

void addDynArr(struct DynArr *v, TYPE val)
{
    // Check to see if a resize is necessary 
    if(v->size >= v->capacity)
    {
        _setCapacityDynArr(v, 2 * v->capacity);
        printf(">>>%d",v->size);   //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<v->size = 0
        v->data[v->size] = val;
        v->size++;

        printf("setcapacity: size is: %d capacity is: %d value is %d value in array is: %d\n", v->size, v->capacity, val, v->data[v->size-1]);


    }
    else
    {


        v->data[v->size] = val;
        v->size++;

       printf("not setcapacity: size is: %d capacity is: %d value is %d value in array is: %d\n", v->size, v->capacity, val, v->data[v->size-1]);


    }

//printf("%d\n", v->capacity);
}

void removeDynArray(struct DynArr *b, TYPE v)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < b->size; i++)
    {
        if(b->data[i] == v)
        {

            while(i < (b->size))
            {
                b->data[i] = b->data[i+1];

                i++;



            }

            break;


        }

    }
    b->size--;
}


void print(struct DynArr *v)
{

    for(int i = 0; i < v->size; i++)
    {

        printf("%d\n", v->data[i]);

    }
}


//do this
void _setCapacityDynArr(struct DynArr *v, int newCap)
{


    struct DynArr* temp;

    temp = v;



   ///print(temp);

    //struct DynArr v;
    v = malloc(sizeof(struct DynArr));

    v->data = malloc(sizeof(TYPE)  * newCap);





    v->capacity = newCap;



    v->size = 0; //temp size is also being set




    for (int i = 0 ; i < temp->size; i++)
    {
        v->data[i] = temp->data[i];

        v->size++;
    }





    free(temp->data);
    temp->size = 0;
    temp->capacity = 0;
    temp = 0;

    printf(">!>>%d",v->size); //////////<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<v->size = 2

}

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{

    struct DynArr a;

    initDynArr(&a, 2);

    addDynArr(&a, 5);

    addDynArr(&a, 7);



    addDynArr(&a, 8);



    //printf("%d\n", a.size);

    //print(&a);

   // printf ("%d\n",a.data[2]);


    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Please paste the code into your question instead of a link. You never know when the link will stop working.

Comment: Please format it too, it's difficult to read.

Answer (score 2):

Your `_setCapacityDynArr` function is written in a rather nonsensical fashion. All functions in this "API" receive a pointer `v` (or, sometimes, `b`) to an existing `struct DynArr` object, which they work with. They can manipulate the fields of `*v` object. They can allocate/deallocate/reallocate the actual array `v->data`. But they never allocate/deallocate the `*v` object itself. Object `*v` is passed from the outside and managed by the outside code.

But your `_setCapacityDynArr` function attempts to do something completely and drastically different. It begins with

```
temp = v;
v = malloc(sizeof(struct DynArr));
...
free(temp);
```

That is already incorrect. This is completely unacceptable. You are not allowed to allocate/deallocate `*v` object itself.

In any case, changing the value of `v` inside the function make no sense simply because `v` is passed to `_setCapacityDynArr` by value. The outside code will not see these changes anyway.

This latter detail is what makes your code to output allegedly "changing" value of `v->size` - you are simply outputing two completely different `v->size` values and one of them actually belongs to deallocated memory. In line 77 you are printing `v->size` value stored in "dead" memory already deallocated by `free(temp)` call inside `_setCapacityDynArr`.

Don't try to acclocate/deallocate `*v` object inside your `_setCapacityDynArr`. Where did you get that idea? Just reallocate `v->data` and change  the other firelds accordingly. But don't attempt to change the value of `v` itself.